# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No bean specified

Tags: java, struts

I am getting this error when I try to submit form. 
Form has two field one is empty and another has some value.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No bean specified
org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyUtilsBean.java:883)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:935)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:830)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:433)
org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:493)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:805)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1063)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:386)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1063)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:386)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: It is difficult to give you some suggestion only viewing the log. Add some more details - jsp/java code and configurations details along with the struts version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be `commons-beanutils` api known issue at `1.8.1`, Upgrading commons-beanutils to `1.9.1` resolved this issue.

BEANUTILS-345