# No bean specified in struts1

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts-1

While submitting the form in struts1 getting the following exception. Is there any way to find the issue?

How we have to find out why we are getting this. I am new to struts1

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No bean specified
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyUtils.java:837)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:934)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:808)
at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:1252)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:821)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:254)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:223)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3245)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2003)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1909)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1359)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
```

Comment: maybe duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543293/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-bean-specified

Comment: I am using 1.9.2 version

Comment: Can you post your action, form and strus-config

Comment: For 1.9.2 getting Invalid index value '5f02ca70-db3b-4993-8d68-1f90e9245a5b'
 

 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid index value '5f02ca70-db3b-4993-8d68-1f90e9245a5b'
 at org.apache.commons.beanutils.expression.DefaultResolver.getIndex(DefaultResolver.java:100)
 at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:911)
 at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:821)

Comment: Is there any other way to find out the detail exception of this bean utils. populate

Comment: can you reproduce this exception with a small example struts project ? And can you post the form,jsp,action and struts-config?

Comment: @pL4Gu33 I will found the issue. In struts action i have 2 forwards. when i tried to submit from second forward having the issue(which is a tile). Do you jnow how to add the formbean in request